# How to get synonyms.txt to be used in solr for different languages

Tags: solr, wordnet, synonym

Do you know if I can get synonyms.txt files for all languages supported by SOLR ?
Thanks for your help.
Before we were using Verity that provide a dictionary of synonyms for each language supported but we want maybe to move to Solr/Lucene.
I know that we can provide a custom synonym list that is no what I want. I am looking  for a way to have a default dictionary of synonyms for each language supported by Lucene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'out of the box' synonym resource provided for all the languages.
At least for some, you have wordnet (which is free) - see the solr wiki for wordnet usage.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I will have a look at wordnet to see if it can help me

Answer (score 1):

A list of synonyms for any language is going to be very specific to the use cases related to a given set of indexed items. For that reason it would not be practical to have any prebuilt language specific versions of these files. Even the synonyms.txt that comes with Solr distribution is only built out enough to show examples of how the synonyms can be constructed.